# Can not save Bitmap Image to a new folder in Android

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm clicking on an image from gallery and trying to save it into a new folder but I'm getting the error below, can someone please help.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: 
    Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
```

Call to saveImage function:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();

        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options);

        cursor.close();
    }
    try {
        saveImage(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}
```

My image saving code:

```
    public void saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) throws IOException {

            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
            myDir.createNewFile();

            String imageName = String.format("%d.png", System.currentTimeMillis());
            File file = new File(myDir, imageName);
            if (file.exists()) file.delete();
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

The error occurs on this line, finalBitmap is always null;

```
    finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Comment: This is because you are receiving a null object at saveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap)

Comment: So how would I solve this ?

Comment: Make sure that you are not passing `null` as the parameter to `saveBitmap()`. We can't help with that, as we cannot see the code where you are making the `saveBitmap()` call and where that `Bitmap` comes from.

Comment: I've added the code where I'm calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this :
replace `myDir.createNewFile();` by `myDir.mkdirs();`
then add this line : `file.createNewFile();` after `File file = new File(myDir, imageName);`

and don't forget to add permission to write in external storage, go to your android manifest and add :
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
then enable the permission in your app in the settings